# Elasticsearch spatial search with terms

Tags: elasticsearch, spatial-index

I am running a query on 140+ million documents with spatial data. Purely spatial queries are extremely fast (sub 1s). Adding a wildcard to the same geometry results in the query taking ~10-20s. I expect wildcard queries to take some time, but I want to know if there is a better way to write the query or trick Elasticsearch into filtering the results to only the geometry and then finding wildcard matches. Or, maybe running the spatial query and then running the wildcard on the resulting doc ids? Any ideas which may result in faster results for the end user would be appreciated.

```json
GET parcels/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name.keyword": {
              "value": "*smith*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "geo_shape": {
                  "shape": {
                    "shape": {
                      "type": "POLYGON",
                      "coordinates": [
                        [
                          [
                            -81.09980486601305,
                            32.063655184739936
                          ],
                          [
                            -81.09980486601168,
                            32.05639855631687
                          ],
                          [
                            -81.09128330779276,
                            32.05639855631687
                          ],
                          [
                            -81.09128330779276,
                            32.06365489826756
                          ],
                          [
                            -81.09980486601305,
                            32.063655184739936
                          ]
                        ]
                      ]
                    },
                    "relation": "intersects"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10000
}
```

our settings for the index:

```json
{
...
"analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
        "search_normalizer": {
            "filter": [
                "uppercase"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
         }
     }
},
"number_of_shards": 8,
"number_of_replicas": 1,
```

mapping for the 'name' field:

```json
"name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "search_normalizer"
        }
    }
},
```

Running ES 7.10. (5 nodes each with 8GB RAM)

Not searching by wildcard is not an option.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a wildcard search with a prefix wildcard (as in `*smith*`) on a `keyword` field is a performance killer!

If you absolutely need this kind of functionality, you need to leverage the new [`wildcard` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) which is meant exactly for this kind of use.

So you can either add another sub-field or change the `keyword` sub-field to a ?wildcard` sub-field.

You can see how it works under the hood in the [blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field) where the wildcard field was described when it came out.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that awesome feature in the release notes... Thank you! I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tested this out on a subset of data and it was a major improvement (~5x). I had to add the [undocumented](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/61162) 'case_insensitive' parameter to replicate current functionality. I'll throw it against the full data set once I re-index. Thanks, again.

Comment: Awesome, glad it provided a meaningful improvement!