# How to write a composite Elasticsearch query including query_string for multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My object looks like this

```
{
      "country_id":3,
      "user_id":22,
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Wright",
      "city_name":"Sydney",
}
```

I want to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE user_id= :1 AND country_id= :2 
AND LOWER(name) LIKE '%' || :3 || '%' 
OR LOWER(surname) LIKE '%' || :4 || '%' 
OR LOWER(city_name) LIKE '%' || :5 || '%' 
OFFSET :6 ROWS FETCH NEXT :7 ROWS ONLY
```

I tried the following:

```
curl -XPOST "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:9200/xxxx/students/_search" -d '{
  "from": 6, "size": 11,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "country_id": "123"
          },
          {
          "term": {
            "user_id": "abc35"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "name:*abc*",
            "query": "surname:*abc*",
            "query": "city_name:*abc*",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

User's search string will be applied on fields name, surname, city_name etc.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing? I want the smallest possible query as there can be multiple fields to be passed in query strings for user's search query to be applied on (like school_name, hobbies, education).

Comment: It is also worth noting that running prefix wildcard queries is not efficient and might hinder the performance of your cluster depending on the volume of data you have. You should see if using the [`wildcard` field type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210784/4604579) instead is more beneficial for your use case.

Comment: @noobie I added a wildcard style query and some links of another approaches. Let elasticsearch to shine and try to avoid the like% style queries. cheers

Answer (score 1):

**Ingest Data**

```
POST test_noobie/_doc
{
  "country_id": 3,
  "user_id": 22,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Wright",
  "city_name": "Sydney"
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_noobie/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*ydn*",
          "fields": [
            "city_name",
            "name",
            "surname"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 22
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "country_id": 3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note I put the id related filters inside the filter scope.This is more efficient because we dont care about scoring on exact matches so it is ommited.

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_noobie",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Tsck7HcB50NMsuQPC1TV",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country_id" : 3,
          "user_id" : 22,
          "name" : "John",
          "surname" : "Wright",
          "city_name" : "Sydney"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Wild cards are expensive by the way, and it is not optimal to use it. You can instead read more about other strategies, I will attach some links :

- [Fuzzy Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)
- [Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) (for 'did you mean' functionalities)
- [Stemming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/stemming.html)

One of the big advantages of moving to a Full text search engine is to use the built in functions as much as possible before starting to use wildcards, regex, or painless scripts.