# Elastic search Ngram tokenizer performance for UUID

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, wildcard, uuid, n-gram

I would like to partial filter on UUID, reference_id, and postal_code. For reference_id and postal_code, I know that they will be shorter than length 36. But UUID are 36 chars long. I'm thinking to set ngram tokenizer with:

min ngram 1

max ngram 36

Will this get really bad overtime in terms of speed and memory? Is there a better way to partial search UUID?
For example I have 7e222584-0818-49b0-875b-2774f4bf939b and I want to be able to search it using 9b0

Comment: The randomness of using a to query UUID is too high, you should reduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will create an awful lot of tokens, actually 36 + 35 + 34 + 33 + ... + 1 = (1 + 36) * (36/2) = 666 tokens for each UUID and that's discouraged. Even when creating an ngram token filter, the default accepted distance between min and max is 1, so you'd have to override that in the index settings, which gives you a first indication that it might not be the right thing todo.

You might want to give a try to the new [`wildcard` query field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66673283/4604579) which [might do a better job](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field).

You can easily compare both approaches by creating two indexes and indexing the same amount (but a substantial one) of UUIDs in both and then comparing their size.

First index with ngrams:

```
PUT uuid1
{
  "settings": {
    "index.max_ngram_diff": 36,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "uuid": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "ngram"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "ngram": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 36
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "uuid": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "uuid",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second index with wildcard:

```
PUT uuid2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "uuid": {
        "type": "wildcard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you index the same data in both:

```
POST _bulk/_doc
{ "index": {"_index": "uuid1"}}
{ "uuid": "7e222584-0818-49b0-875b-2774f4bf939b"}
{ "index": {"_index": "uuid2"}}
{ "uuid": "7e222584-0818-49b0-875b-2774f4bf939b"}
```

And finally you can compare their size and you can see that the `uuid` index will be bigger than the `uuid2` index. Here by a factor of 3, but you might want to index a bit more data to figure out a better ratio:

```
GET _cat/shards/uuid*?v

index shard prirep state   docs  store ip          node
uuid1 0     p      STARTED    1 10.6kb 10.0.33.86  instance-0000000062
uuid2 0     p      STARTED    1  3.5kb 10.0.12.26  instance-0000000042
```

Searching on the second index leveraging `wildcard`, can be done very easily like this, so it's a simple as a `match` query you'd do on the index with ngrams:

```
POST uuid2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "uuid": "*9b0*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i know about the wildcard field type, but from what i understand, its bad to put * in front and end of the term for performance.. perhaps maybe I should differentiate? for postal code and reference_id i can use ngram, but for UUID i should use wildcard?

Comment: It's not only about the wildcard query, for which it's indeed bad to use leading *, but also about the [new `wildcard` field](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field) which has been created exactly for this purpose. So the combo, wildcard field+query works best for your use case

Comment: so you meant its OK if i use query term \*9b0\* for wildcard field?

Comment: Please follow the link I referenced twice :-)

Comment: ok, how to search using uuid1 index?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi please feel free to create a new question for your specific issue