# Query DSL regexp pattern doesn't work with some strings

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a pattern ".*TP-V.*" which returns strings like "SSTP-VPN". But the pattern ".*SSH.*" Does not return anything, although there are lines like "core:Login:SSH:Cisco". I have no idea what pattern is need.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use the new wildcard field type for this purpose as regular expression are not performant at all: https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672162/elastic-search-wildcard-query-with-space-failing-7-11/66673283#66673283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `".*SSH.*"` instead of `".SSH."`.
Adding a working example -

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"core:Login:SSH:Cisco"
}
{
    "name":"SSTP-VPN"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "name.keyword": {
        "value": ".*SSH.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "68015371",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "core:Login:SSH:Cisco"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "name.keyword": {
        "value": ".*TP-V.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```